# Reduce Loud Sounds on Apple TV programmatically

Tags: avplayer, tvos, apple-tv, avplayerviewcontroller

The top menu on Apple's AVPlayerViewController shows the Audio options:

- Full Dynamic Range
- Reduce Loud Sounds

Is there a way to select these audio options programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible according to the tvOS Apple Docs for `AVPlayer`. The only audio output properties they give you access to are `muted` and `volume`.

[**AVPlayer Class Reference: Managing Audio Output**](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayer/volume)